# How to trigger an event which uses closure variables?

Tags: javascript, debugging, closures, pixi.js

In a Pixi.js game I want to simulate a mouse click on canvas. In the code below the event is in a closure but I want to trigger this from outside. 
If this is possible can you help me to figure out how can I do this from browser console?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwLwkebo/4/

HTML:

```
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  const Container = PIXI.Container,
    autoDetectRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer,
    loader = PIXI.loader,
    resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
    Sprite = PIXI.Sprite,
    Point = PIXI.Point,
    width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

  const renderer = autoDetectRenderer(width, height),
    stage = new Container();

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

  loader
    .add('pixel', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/751168765191081988/3y6h5fRA.jpg')
    .load(go);

  function go() {
    const pixelContainer = new Container(),
      pixel = new Sprite(resources.pixel.texture);

    pixelContainer.name = 'pixelContainer';
    pixelContainer.interactive = true;
    pixelContainer.on('mousedown', event => {
      console.log(`Container clicked (${pixelContainer.name})`);
    });

    pixel.name = 'pixel';
    pixel.width = width;
    pixel.height = height;
    pixel.interactive = true;
    pixel.on('mousedown', event => {
      console.log(`Sprite clicked (${pixel.name})`);
    });

    pixelContainer.addChild(pixel);
    stage.addChild(pixelContainer);

    renderer.render(stage);

    setTimeout(simulateClick, 3000);
  }

  const el = document.querySelector('canvas');

  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('Canvas clicked');
  });

  function simulateClick(mode) {
    const x = 10,
      y = 10,
      ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true,
        'clientX': x,
        'clientY': y
      });

    if (mode) document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(ev);
    else el.dispatchEvent(ev);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the function `simulateClick()` available in Dev Tools's console, you can:

- open the Dev Tools and go to the `Sources` tab
- load the page
- find where the function is defined in the Sources tab in the source code
- set a breakpoint there
- reload the page
- when the execution paused after your function definition, go to the `Console` tab in Dev Tools
- write `window.simulate = simulateClick` (or whatever function you want to access) and press enter
- resume the execution of the page
- now, in console, you can run `simulate(true)` and your function will be executed